# Pass checkbox values into an array using ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am needing some help passing checkbox values into an array using ajax and retrieving the values in my controller. The following code is not working. I receive the error: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". Var_dump gives `string(42) "Educator_Classes[]=1&Educator_Classes;[]=3`

Thanks for any help you can provide.

My html form input:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Educator_Classes[]" name="Educator_Classes" class="Educator_Classes" value="<?php echo $Class_Number; ?>"/>
```

My jquery:

```
$("#Send_Invite").click(function() {
    var form_data = {
        Opportunity_Id: $('#Opportunity_Id').val(),
        Educator_Id: $('#Educator_Id').val(),
        Educator_Classes: $('#Educator_Classes:checked').serialize(),
        ajax: '1'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('schedule/update_educator_class'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#response').html(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
})
```

My controller:

```
function update_educator_class() {
    $Educator_Id = $this->input->post('Educator_Id');
    $Opportunity_Id = $this->input->post('Opportunity_Id');
    $Educator_Classes = $this->input->post('Educator_Classes');

    foreach($Educator_Classes as $Educator_Class):
        $this->ion_auth_model->update_educator_class($Opportunity_Id, $Educator_Class, $Educator_Id);
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: Select educator_classes like this `Educator_Classes: $('[id="Educator_Classes[]"]').serialize()`or  `Educator_Classes: $('#Educator_Classes\\[\\]').serialize()`

Comment: @Anton Hmm, tried both and still getting the same result. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Ah i noticed it's the classes you want. You need to use class indicator **`.`** `$('.Educator_Classes:checked')`

Comment: @Anton Still same error w/ `Educator_Classes: $('.Educator_Classes\\[\\]').serialize()`.

Comment: without `[]` it should be `$('.Educator_Classes:checked').serialize()`

Comment: @Anton I must have something else wrong. Using the code you mentioned in the comment above and `<input type="checkbox" id="Educator_Classes" name="Educator_Classes[]" class="Educator_Classes" value="<?php echo $Class_Number; ?>"/>` I still receive the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60979/discussion-between-user1337595-and-anton).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `[]` for name attribute and not for `id`, otherwise it can't act like an array

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Educator_Classes" name="Educator_Classes[]" class="Educator_Classes" value="<?php echo $Class_Number; ?>"/>
```

And also your jQuery code can be simpler:

```
$("#Send_Invite").click(function() {
    var form_data = $(this).closest('form).serialize();
    form_data['ajax'] = 1;

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('schedule/update_educator_class'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#response').html(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

To debut what's passed to `$Educator_Classes` you can do this:

```
var_export($Educator_Classes);
```

Comment: var_dump gives `string(24) "Educator_Classes[]=1&Educator_Classes;[]=3`

Comment: Serializing the entire form solved the problem! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Solution is that you have to take the array of name attribute of checkbox.
 Like :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Educator_Classes[]" name="Educator_Classes[]" class="Educator_Classes" value="<?php echo $Class_Number; ?>"/>
```

Comment: Use this<input type="checkbox" id="Educator_Classes" name="Educator_Classes[]" class="Educator_Classes" value="<?php echo $Class_Number; ?>"/>

Comment: That is what I am using, with the same result...`<input type="checkbox" id="Educator_Classes" name="Educator_Classes[]" class="Educator_Classes" value="<?php echo $Class_Number; ?>"/>`